# Beacon monitoring keeping location services on, indefinately. iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My iPhone app registers for significant location change. When on location change is called, I start beacon region monitoring for all the beacon in certain range of user's location.

My app needs to identify that user has entered into a beacon region (irrespective of whether app is running or not). To achieve this, we did following things:

-- set `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay` flag to true for beacon regions:

```
beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true;
```

-- set Required background modes in pList to bluetooth-central. for ref. [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)

I am not sure what got it working. But it turns out our app does not turn location services off, once started.

Is it possible to get significant location change update and beacon region entered update when location service is off? 
Do I need to set Required background modes to get this working in background?

Comment: Why do you suppose that location services will send you any updates if location services are turned off. If this happens in any way, then that is a flaw in iOS and you should not build your solution on it because Apple will probably correct such issues. Also, could you correct the wording: "But it turns out our app does to turn location services off, once started" does not really make sense to me.

Comment: @allprog I mean once the app is not running in the foreground, it still shows that the location service is in active use on the status bar of the iPhone. If you use other app, like Google maps, if you open the application it will show the icon on the iPhone status bar, but if you get out of the app, location service will go away from iPhone status bar. 
The problem we are facing is battery usage because of active use of the location service. I was not talking about manual turning on or off of the location service by the user.

Comment: The apps you mention probably have a hook at the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification (or similar) notification and they intentionally turn off monitoring. The Maps app uses GPS so it definitely does this. If you want to monitor for beacons only when the app is in foreground, then hook on the mentioned notification or the corresponding method in the app delegate and turn the monitoring off when it is called.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant, but if you ask why iBeacon is still ranging even when the app is not running, it's actually an update from Apple : http://beekn.net/2014/03/apple-ios-7-1-launches-major-ibeacon-improvement/

Answer (score 2):

When you using iBeacon to monitor for specific region it will always display location icon on status bar, even when app is closed.

To disable location service for your app try to call method bellow for all you registered regions when going to background:

```
- (void)stopMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

And to use iBeacon in background you actually need not "bluetooth-central" mode but "location".

Comment: you need neither - location is for GPS only IIRC

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to keep background mode - location updates ON for beacon ranging.

For background execution, just use `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` and your code will work in background as well.

check my answer [iBeacon ranging in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016992/ibeacon-ranging-in-the-background/30867099#30867099) here.