# iBeacon ranging in background

Tags: ios, location, ibeacon

I'm seeing huge difference in how iBeacon ranging works on iOS 8.X and iOS 9 beta.

On iOS 8.X I'm able to range beacons in background (ranging continues to work when app is in background and the screen is off), but on iOS 9, it stops once app goes to background, turning the screen on and off, will resume ranging for couple of seconds, and then it stops again.

Does anybody else experience this? If so did you find a solution for iOS 9?

Comment: How long are you seeing background ranging work on iOS 8.x?  Background ranging is not supposed to work for more than 10 seconds after an app transitions to the background unless you take special measures to extend it.  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

Comment: I was able to make it work for hours

Answer (score 2):

OK,
Setting `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES` on CLLocationManager I'm using to range for beacons, seems to solve this problem, and I'm able to continue to range for beacons in the background as before.

Comment: Be careful about that setting if you want to submit your app to the AppStore, as it will not be approved unless you can convince reviewers that you have created a navigation app.

Comment: Yep, it shouldn't be used lightly, but in our case its required for the app to function. I hope that if they approved the app on iOS 8, they will do the same for iOS 9 as well.

Answer (score 2):

if you use ios 9 or later  you should add all the request location statement 
 Access to location is still permitted
      whenever the application is running (ie not suspended), and has
   sufficient authorization (ie it has WhenInUse authorization and is in
      use, or it has Always authorization).

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

Now to allow the background mode you need to add this link
     `self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;`

Discussion:
      By default, this is NO for applications linked against iOS 9.0 or later,
    regardless of minimum deployment target.

With `UIBackgroundModes set to include "location" in Info.plist`, you must Setting this property to **YES** when UIBackgroundModes does not include "location" is a fatal error.

Resetting this property to **NO** is equivalent to omitting "location" from
      the UIBackgroundModes value.

Answer (score 0):

***i've copied Gualtier's response from [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/10774) 
Personnaly i found it very helpful with a clear explanation! Hope that could help you***

The location updates will start in either case. What changes is, when the startUpdatingLocation call is made while the app is in the foreground (and the 'location' UIBackgroundMode is set), the system holds a background task assertion for your app; meaning your app will not be suspended as long as the location updates are running.

In the case of calling startUpdatingLocation while your app is in the **background**, CoreLocation still responds by starting the location updates for your app, but the system will no longer hold an assertion for you, and your app **will be suspended** once the allowed time in the background is spent. The documentation is technically correct - you can start location updates from either state - staying active withuot being suspended is another story.

This time is (currently) is **10 seconds**, which is why you think updates stop after 10 seconds. But actually your app is **now suspended and can no longer receive the updates**. There is a way to extend this duration to (currently) up to 3 minutes by employing beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: (Read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1

Whether this extended time is enough will depend on your app.

If your goal in trying to wait until later to start location updates is power saving, there are other ways as well.
- if it is suitable for your use case, Significant Location Change service is quite efficient, and a better match to use in conjunction with the standard location service
- you can start location updates when your app is in the foreground and defer location updates while your app is in the background. As your app tracks journeys which would have a start and an end, having location updates running during the journey, while deferring the updates could be suitable for your case.
When the updates are deferred, the system will wake your app when it decides it is power efficient to do so. You can read more about that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW14

Also, I suggest you watch the WWDC 2015 presentation "What's new in Core Location" **to find out what is coming in iOS 9.** There is a new way to get the current location easily which might be of interest to you, and there is an additional step to get background location updates to work. The video is here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=714

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't really help much with iBeacon ranging, since that relies on region monitoring APIs and not on location updates.

Answer (score -1):

For background execution, just use `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` and your code will work in background as well.

check my answer [iBeacon ranging in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016992/ibeacon-ranging-in-the-background/30867099#30867099)

Comment: You solution only gives couple of seconds running in background, which is good, but not good enough for my purpose, with allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates set to YES, application continues to run in the background for ever, ranging beacons nearby